# Flasque Constant Sheaf

Tags: sheaf-theory

It is easy to show that if $X$ is an irreducible topological space, then the constant sheaf $\mathbb{Z}$ is flasque.  Is the converse true?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Flasqueness is a local condition, but irreducibility is not. Indeed, let $X = X_1 = X_2$ be an irreducible topological space and let $Y = X_1 \amalg X_2$. For any sheaf $\mathscr{F}$ on $Y$ and any open $V \subseteq Y$,
$$\Gamma (V, \mathscr{F}) \cong \Gamma (V \cap X_1, \mathscr{F}) \times \Gamma (V \cap X_2, \mathscr{F})$$
so if the restrictions $\mathscr{F} |_{X_1}$ and $\mathscr{F} |_{X_2}$ are flasque, then so is $\mathscr{F}$. In particular, $\mathbb{Z}$ is flasque on $Y$, but $Y$ is not irreducible (because it is not connected!).

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  If you add the additional condition that X is connected, is it true?

Comment: If you know that $X$ is connected and locally connected, then you can deduce that every open subset of $X$ is connected (or empty). I don't see why this implies $X$ is irreducible, however.

Comment: Is this correct?  If every open subset of the connected space $X$ is connected and $\mathbb{Z}$ is flasque, but $X$ is not irreducible, then there exist disjoint nonempty open subsets $U,V \subseteq X$.  Then the restriction map $\mathbb{Z}(X)=\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}(U \cup V)=\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ cannot be surjective.  So every two nonempty open subsets intersect after all.

Comment: @ZhenLin Is it true that, if for an open cover $\{U_i\}$ we have that $\mathscr{F}\mid_{U_i}$ is flasque for each $i$, then $\mathscr{F}$ is Flasque?